# Unable to push data into array node.js from html page

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, object

I am trying to make a simple webpage that takes input from a form and stores in an array. Here's the code. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Please help.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const homeStartingContent = "abc";

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

var posts = [];

app.get("/", function(req, res){

  res.render("home", {startingContent:homeStartingContent});
  console.log(posts);

});


app.get("/compose", function(req, res){

  res.render("compose");
  
});

app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
  const post = {
    title : req.body.userTitle,
    posta : req.body.userPost
  };
 
  posts.push(post);
  
  res.redirect("/");
 
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});


<%- include("./partials/header"); -%>

<br>
<h1>Compose</h1>
<form action="/compose" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userTitle">
      <label>Post</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="userPost" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Publish</button>

<%- include("./partials/footer"); -%>
```

I tried passing the route hardcoded but that didn't work either. Searched stack overflow for solutions but didn't get one that explains exactly what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This issue is fixed. It was a small mistake. I added the submit button outside the form which wasn't allowing me submit data from html page.